# Xamarin.Forms - BeginInvokeOnMainThread for an async Action

Tags: c#, xamarin, async-await, xamarin.forms

I am familiar with the rules about updating UI elements on the UI thread using the Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread, however I have an operation that needs to be run on the UI thread that is actually a Task.

For example, the Push/PopAsync methods on XLabs.Forms.Mvvm seem to behave incorrectly on iOS unless they are invoked on the UI thread. There is also another example in the Acr.UserDialogs library for displaying toasts etc.

I know that making an Action async is basically creating an async void lambda and runs the risk of creating a deadlock in the case of an exception, obviously I don't want this to happen.

Does anybody have a workaround for performing async operations on the UI thread that doesn't involve marking the Action as async?

Comment: How would an exception cause a deadlock?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just make sure you handle exceptions in your Action and you should be fine. The problem you described occurs when you **don't** handle the exceptions. Below is a very simple example of running an async method from the main thread.

```
private void Test()
{
    Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(SomeMethod);
}

private async void SomeMethod()
{
    try
    {
        await SomeAsyncMethod();
    }
    catch (Exception e) // handle whatever exceptions you expect
    {
        //Handle exceptions
    }
}

private async Task SomeAsyncMethod()
{
    await Navigation.PushModalAsync(new ContentPage());
}
```

Answer (score 24):

Since **Xamarin.Forms 4.2** there is now a helper method to run tasks on the main thread and await them.

```cs
await Device.InvokeOnMainThreadAsync(SomeAsyncMethod);
```

Several overloads exist that should cover most scenarios:

```
System.Threading.Tasks.Task InvokeOnMainThreadAsync (System.Action action);
System.Threading.Tasks.Task InvokeOnMainThreadAsync (System.Func<System.Threading.Tasks.Task> funcTask);
System.Threading.Tasks.Task<T> InvokeOnMainThreadAsync<T> (System.Func<System.Threading.Tasks.Task<T>> funcTask);
System.Threading.Tasks.Task<T> InvokeOnMainThreadAsync<T> (System.Func<T> func);
```

Related PR: https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/pull/5028

NOTE: the PR had some bug that was fixed in v4.2, so don't use this in v4.1.

Answer (score 6):

Dropping this here in case someone wants to await the end of an action which has to be executed on the main thread

```
public static class DeviceHelper
{
    public static Task RunOnMainThreadAsync(Action action)
    {
        var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<object>();
        Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(
            () =>
            {
                try
                {
                    action();
                    tcs.SetResult(null);
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    tcs.SetException(e);
                }
            });

        return tcs.Task;
    }

    public static Task RunOnMainThreadAsync(Task action)
    {
        var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<object>();
        Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(
            async () =>
            {
                try
                {
                    await action;
                    tcs.SetResult(null);
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    tcs.SetException(e);
                }
            });

        return tcs.Task;
    }
}
```

Comment: I understand the purpose of your first function, but how about the second? the task is not started in the main thread but just awaited in it

Comment: if action is async void it will match function one and the end of that call won't be awaitable - the second one enables scenarios where you want to await the execution of the method(Task) you're passing.

Comment: scenarios where you want to await the function... on the main thread? why would you want that?

Comment: sometimes the code you want to run has to be executed on the ui thread. what exactly is so suprising for you about that?

Comment: well, even if you await on the main thread, it doesn't mean the execution will continue on that thread, AFAIU (see ConfigueAwait(bool))

Comment: no. of course not - that's not what this method is intended to. it's merely a method to await the end of something which using the natural api would not be awaitable

Comment: but you already have the `Task` object anyway, if after the await finishes you don't know if the current thread is the main thread or not, you could just await it on your own, without using that new helper that you created

Comment: That is the whole point of the helper method... being sure that it is run on the UI thread and knowing when it is done. If you want to run something on the background use Task.Run.

Comment: you're clearly not understanding what you are saying

Comment: @knocte - `await` by default resumes **on the captured context**. If on main thread, do `await` without any `ConfigureAwait(bool)`, that is guaranteed to perform continuation on the main thread. In second snippet, `Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread` ensures `await action` executes on main thread. This answer looks correct to me. Perhaps there is a simpler way to ensure that?

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve FYI after I engaged in this conversation here, I contributed a PR to Xamarin.Forms to add more RunOnMainThread overloads (and it got merged); you might want to check them out

Comment: explained in the accepted answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56901805/544947

Comment: @knocte - actually I was investigating the underlying behavior of `async/await`, looking for any evidence that might explain [this SO question's symptom](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72064763/199364). I believe the code itself is okay; I suspect a latent issue in XForms itself. Possibly revealed by its use of `InvokeOnMainThreadAsync`, which changes *when* the code gets executed. FYI my reference to "a simpler way" didn't mean using those newer methods - I was pondering how that 2nd snippet used async/await.

Comment: I just had a look at https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/5.0.0/Xamarin.Forms.Core/Device.cs and I see the functions are a bit different than what I contributed in the first place; they look alright except the ones in lines 134 and 155, which have suspicious await keywords inside the call to original BeginInvokeOnMainThread

Answer (score 0):

Evaluating the Maui framework and the related [WeatherTwentyOne](https://github.com/davidortinau/WeatherTwentyOne) demo. The dialogs were throwing exceptions on Android 29 related to auth modifications. Hat tip to this post [Why does my app crash after alert dialog buttons are clicked](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67980552/241296)

Anyway, I could not locate the aforementioned async helpers. So I adapted [@Dbl's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47941859/241296) post to include awaitable generic results (or not)

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Maui.Controls;

// ReSharper disable AsyncVoidLambda

namespace WeatherTwentyOne.Utils
{
    public static class DeviceHelper
    {
        // https://stackoverflow.com/a/47941859/241296

        public static Task<T> RunOnMainThreadAsync<T>(Func<Task<T>> op)
        {
            var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<T>();
            Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async
                () => {
                try
                {
                    var t = await op();
                    tcs.SetResult(t);
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    tcs.SetException(e);
                }
            });

            return tcs.Task;
        }

        public static Task RunOnMainThreadAsync(Func<Task> op)
        {
            var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource();
            Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async
                () => {
                try
                {
                    await op();
                    tcs.SetResult();
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    tcs.SetException(e);
                }
            });

            return tcs.Task;
        }
    }
}
```

Example usage:

```
var password = await Utils.DeviceHelper.RunOnMainThreadAsync<string>(async () => await DisplayPromptAsync("Login", "Enter password"));
```

**Edit: 2022-03-26**

In response to the following warning:

*BeginInvokeOnMainThread(Action) is obsolete: Use BindableObject.Dispatcher.Dispatch() instead*

implementation revised to:

```
public static class DeviceHelper
{

  public static Task<T> RunOnMainThreadAsync<T>(Func<Task<T>> op)
  {
    var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<T>();

    Application.Current?.Dispatcher.Dispatch(async () =>
    {
      try
      {
        var t = await op();
        tcs.SetResult(t);
      }
      catch (Exception e)
      {
        tcs.SetException(e);
      }
    });

    return tcs.Task;
  }

  public static Task RunOnMainThreadAsync(Func<Task> op)
  {
    var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource();

    Application.Current?.Dispatcher.Dispatch(async () =>
    {
      try
      {
        await op();
        tcs.SetResult();
      }
      catch (Exception e)
      {
        tcs.SetException(e);
      }
    });

    return tcs.Task;
  }
}
```