# Xamarin - Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x69432220 in tid 1959 (Finalizer)

Tags: c#, multithreading, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I was looking for the error on the internet and I found that my error is probably generated because I have a method that is sending changes in the data link without sending the user interface thread, I found that I can resolve this problem through the implementation of **Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread** / **UI thread**. But I do not know completely how to implement it in my project or in any case in the method that I am working on.

This is the error that I am receiving

> No native Android stacktrace (see debuggerd output).
>
> Got a SIGSEGV while executing native code. This usually indicates 07-10 16:38:07.878 E/mono-rt ( 1929): a fatal error in the mono runtime or one of the native libraries 07-10 16:38:07.878 E/mono-rt ( 1929): used by your application.
>
> Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x69432220 in tid 1959 (Finalizer)

```
public void CheckCitas()
    {

        Debug.WriteLine("-------------------------------------Eventos checados------------------------------------");
        // Handle when your app sleeps
        List<Cita> citas = memberDatabase.GetCitasL();
        int citCount = citas.Count();

        if (citCount > 0)
        {
            foreach (Cita ct in citas)
            {
                var dt = ct.fecha;
                var ft = ct.hora;
                var idx = ct.ID;
                var razon = ct.razon;
                var desc = ct.descripcion;

                //  string ft_f = TimeSpan.Parse(ft).ToString();


                if (ft == "11:0")
                {
                    ft = ft + "0";
                }
                ft = ft.Replace(" ",string.Empty);
                int ft_len = ft.Length;

                switch (ft_len)
                {
                    case (5):
                        if (DateTime.TryParseExact(dt, "yyyy-MM-dd", null, DateTimeStyles.AssumeLocal, out DateTime datetime_))
                        {
                            dt = datetime_.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy"); //hay que probar este y el de 4
                        }
                        var chckdrx = dt + " " + ft;
                        DateTime dtchckx = DateTime.ParseExact(chckdrx.Trim(), "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm",
                        System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);



                        DateTime nowx = DateTime.Now;
                        var result_tx = DateTime.Compare(dtchckx, nowx);

                        var tm10x = dtchckx - nowx;
                        var tmm = tm10x.Minutes;
                        if (tmm < 0)
                        {
                            var ctExp = new CitaExp();
                            ctExp.descripcion = desc;
                            ctExp.fecha = dt;
                            ctExp.hora = ft;
                            ctExp.ID = idx;
                            ctExp.razon = razon;

                            //memberDatabase.AddCitaExp(ctExp);
                         
                                memberDatabase.DeleteCita(idx);
                            
                           
                            Debug.WriteLine("---------------------------------------Alarma eliminada -------------------------------------");
                        }
                        if (tmm <= 5)
                            {
                                var v = CrossVibrate.Current;
                                v.Vibration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3));
                                CrossLocalNotifications.Current.Show("Faltan " + tmm + " minutos para tu cita " + ct.razon, "");
                            }

                            if  (tmm == 0)
                            {
                                //var ctI = new CitaInfo(idx);
                                //ctI.RingAlarm();


                                var v = CrossVibrate.Current;
                                v.Vibration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(12));
                                Debug.WriteLine("-----------------------------------------------Alarma Sonando-------------------------------------");
                                CrossLocalNotifications.Current.Show("Tú cita " + razon + " es ahora !!!", "Entiendo");

                                //DependencyService.Get<IAudio>().PlayAudioFile("softAlarm.mp3");
                                var assembly = typeof(App).GetTypeInfo().Assembly;
                                Stream audioFile = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("DateEventos.Reso.softAlarm.mp3");
                                var audio = Plugin.SimpleAudioPlayer.CrossSimpleAudioPlayer.Current;
                                audio.Load(audioFile);

                                audio.Play();
                                //try
                                //{
                                Debug.WriteLine("-----------------------------------------------Expirando cita-------------------------------------");
                                var ctExp = new CitaExp();
                                ctExp.descripcion = desc;
                                ctExp.fecha = dt;
                                ctExp.hora = ft;
                                ctExp.ID = idx;
                                ctExp.razon = razon;

                                Expirando(idx.ToString());

                                memberDatabase.AddCitaExp(ctExp);
                                memberDatabase.DeleteCita(idx);



                                // }
                                //catch (Exception ex)
                                //{
                                //    Debug.WriteLine("--------------------------Error_" + ex.ToString() + "-------------------------------------");
                                //    throw;
                                //}
                            }
                        



                        break;
                    case (3):

                        string outputdt = ft.Substring(ft.Length - 1, 1);
                        if (outputdt == "0")
                        {
                            ft = ft + "0";
                        }

                        if (DateTime.TryParseExact(dt, "yyyy-MM-dd", null, DateTimeStyles.AssumeLocal, out DateTime datetime))
                        {
                            dt = datetime.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");
                        }
                        var chckdr = dt + " " + ft;
                        DateTime dtchck = DateTime.ParseExact(chckdr.Trim(), "dd-MM-yyyy H:mm",
                        System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);




                        DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
                        var result_t = DateTime.Compare(dtchck, now);

                        var tm10 = dtchck - now;
                        var tmmi = tm10.Minutes;
                        if (tmmi < 0)
                        {
                            var ctExp = new CitaExp();
                            ctExp.descripcion = desc;
                            ctExp.fecha = dt;
                            ctExp.hora = ft;
                            ctExp.ID = idx;
                            ctExp.razon = razon;

                            //memberDatabase.AddCitaExp(ctExp);
                            memberDatabase.DeleteCita(idx);
                            Debug.WriteLine("---------------------------------------Alarma eliminada -------------------------------------");

                        }
                         if (tmmi <= 5)
                            {
                                var v = CrossVibrate.Current;
                                v.Vibration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3));
                                CrossLocalNotifications.Current.Show("Faltan " + tmmi + " minutos para tu cita " + ct.razon, "");
                            }

                             if (tmmi == 0)
                            {
                                var v = CrossVibrate.Current;
                                v.Vibration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(12));
                                Debug.WriteLine("-----------------------------------------------Alarma Sonando-------------------------------------");
                                CrossLocalNotifications.Current.Show("Tú cita " + razon + " es ahora !!!", "Entiendo");

                                //DependencyService.Get<IAudio>().PlayAudioFile("softAlarm.mp3");
                                var assembly = typeof(App).GetTypeInfo().Assembly;
                                Stream audioFile = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("DateEventos.Reso.softAlarm.mp3");
                                var audio = Plugin.SimpleAudioPlayer.CrossSimpleAudioPlayer.Current;
                                audio.Load(audioFile);


                                audio.Play();
                                var ctExp = new CitaExp();
                                ctExp.descripcion = desc;
                                ctExp.fecha = dt;
                                ctExp.hora = ft;
                                ctExp.ID = idx;
                                ctExp.razon = razon;


                                Expirando(idx.ToString());

                                memberDatabase.AddCitaExp(ctExp);

                                memberDatabase.DeleteCita(idx);


                            }
                        

                        break;

                    case (4):

                        //string outputdtx = ft.Substring(ft.Length - 1, 1);
                        //if (outputdtx == "0")
                        //{
                        //    ft = ft + "0";
                        //}

                        if (DateTime.TryParseExact(dt, "yyyy-MM-dd", null, DateTimeStyles.AssumeLocal, out DateTime datetimex))
                        {
                            dt = datetimex.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");
                        }
                        var chckdrxx = dt + " " + ft;
                        DateTime dtchckxx = DateTime.ParseExact(chckdrxx.Trim(), "dd-MM-yyyy H:mm",
                        System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);




                        DateTime nowxx = DateTime.Now;
                        var result_txx = DateTime.Compare(dtchckxx, nowxx);

                        var tm10xx = dtchckxx - nowxx;
                        var tmmix = tm10xx.Minutes;
                        if (tmmix < 0)
                        {
                            var ctExp = new CitaExp();
                            ctExp.descripcion = desc;
                            ctExp.fecha = dt;
                            ctExp.hora = ft;
                            ctExp.ID = idx;
                            ctExp.razon = razon;

                            //memberDatabase.AddCitaExp(ctExp);
                            memberDatabase.DeleteCita(idx);
                            Debug.WriteLine("---------------------------------------Alarma eliminada -------------------------------------");

                        }
                        
                            if (tmmix <= 5)
                            {
                                var v = CrossVibrate.Current;
                                v.Vibration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3));
                                CrossLocalNotifications.Current.Show("Faltan " + tmmix + " minutos para tu cita " + ct.razon, "");
                            }

                            if (tmmix == 0)
                            {
                                var v = CrossVibrate.Current;
                                v.Vibration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(12));
                                Debug.WriteLine("-----------------------------------------------Alarma Sonando-------------------------------------");
                                CrossLocalNotifications.Current.Show("Tú cita " + razon + " es ahora !!!", "Entiendo");

                                //DependencyService.Get<IAudio>().PlayAudioFile("softAlarm.mp3");
                                var assembly = typeof(App).GetTypeInfo().Assembly;
                                Stream audioFile = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("DateEventos.Reso.softAlarm.mp3");
                                var audio = Plugin.SimpleAudioPlayer.CrossSimpleAudioPlayer.Current;
                                audio.Load(audioFile);

                                audio.Play();

                                Debug.WriteLine("-----------------------------------------------Expirando cita-------------------------------------");
                                var ctExp = new CitaExp();
                                ctExp.descripcion = desc;
                                ctExp.fecha = dt;
                                ctExp.hora = ft;
                                ctExp.ID = idx;
                                ctExp.razon = razon;

                                memberDatabase.AddCitaExp(ctExp);
                                Expirando(idx.ToString());

                                memberDatabase.DeleteCita(idx);


                            }
                        
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
       

    }
```

I would like to know how to deal with this type of problem or how to implement a **Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread** for a method, I do not upload my full console error because it is very long. Thank you all.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39673153/xamarin-forms-begininvokeonmainthread-for-an-async-action

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are not posting your code, the usage for the method is like this. Usually, when you want to update UI elements, you do this using this method.

```
Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread (() => {
  label.Text = "Async operation completed";
});
```