# Can I change the UI from a method that gets data (not async) that has been called with await?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have this code:

```
    protected override async void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();            
        Subscribe();
        vm.IsBusy = true;
        if (Change.firstTimeCardsTab == true)
        {
            SetButtons(Settings.cc.ShortText());
            await Task.Run(() => GetOnAppearingData());
        }
    }

    private void GetOnAppearingData()
    {
        App.DB.GetData();
        AddDetailSection();
        SetPageDetails();
        Change.firstTimeCardsTab = false;
        vm.IsBusy = false;
    }
```

vm.IsBusy = true; shows an activity indicator on the page and vm.IsBusy = false; would I hoped turn it off.

However when I run the code I get a message saying:

> UIKit Consistency error: you are calling a UIKit method that can only
>   be invoked from a UI thread.

Can someone give me advice on how I can set the activity indicator to show, then get the data and then set it to not show? Note that AddDetailSection(); adds some elements to the XAML. Could this be the problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Xamarin.Forms - BeginInvokeOnMainThread for an async Action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39673153/xamarin-forms-begininvokeonmainthread-for-an-async-action)

Comment: I tried this but it gives a message saying "cannot convert from void to system action".  Could you perhaps give an example answer that I could use for this. Note that App.DB.GetData is not an async method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UI can be manipulated only from the main thread. There is a method `Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(Action)` that can help to solve your issue, more can be found in the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.device.begininvokeonmainthread?view=xamarin-forms).

Just wrap all UI related actions by it:
`Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => {
    SetPageDetails();
    // Any other actions
});`