# Why does my app crash after alert dialog buttons are clicked

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.forms

I have a DisplayPromptAsync it crashes my app when one of the two buttons is clicked.

It still does what it is suppose to do then crashes the app.

DisplayPromptAsync Function
RejectButton_Clicked = new Command(get => RejectClick());

```
    public async void RejectClick()
    {
        try
        {
            rejectReason = await Application.Current.MainPage.DisplayPromptAsync("Reject Reason",
                "Are you sure you want to reject Order Number: " + selectedItem.OrderNumber
                + " and Company: " + selectedItem.Company, "OK", "Cancel");
            SendReject();
            GetData();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            await Application.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Error", ex.ToString(), "OK");
        }
    }
```

Send Reject function

```
    private async void SendReject()
    {
        try
        {
            string requestUrl = "https://mist.zp.co.za:6502/MIST.svc/REJ/M@H$@203@R/" + selectedItem.OrderNumber +
                "/" + selectedItem.Company + "/" + rejectReason;
            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(requestUrl);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            await Application.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Error", ex.ToString(), "OK");
        }
    }
```

Get Data function

```
    private async void GetData()
    {
        MistHeaders.Clear();
        string requestUrl = "https://mist.zp.co.za:6502/MIST.svc/head/M@H$@203@R";
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(requestUrl);
            try
            {
                if (response.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
                {
                    string content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    MistHeaders root = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MistHeaders>(content);
                    List<Models.Table> dates = root.Table;

                    foreach (var item in dates)
                    {
                        MistHeaders.Add(item);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                await Application.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Error", ex.ToString(), "OK");
            }
        }
    }
```

I've added the other two functions for relevance.

Something I forgot it works perfectly fine on emulator just not on physical device

Comment: You better not swallow all exceptions. Your problem may be that you don't `await` SendReject and GetData (you have to declare them as `async Task` instead of `async void` to be awaitable).

Comment: @KlausGütter Hi Klaus I added that it works perfectly on the emulator just not on a physical device hope this helps

Comment: the Exception details will tell you exactly why it is crashing.  You need to examine them in the debugger or output them to the console instead of just throwing them away

Comment: @Jason Can I directly debug to a physical device? It is only the physical device giving me this issue. I don't have a problem debugging on the emulator because I don't get a error or a crash there.

Comment: Yes, you can debug on a physical device

Comment: @Jason There is no error in the output or an exception thrown. I edited my code so that it will return the exception. Se edit in post as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The crash is caused by button click , but this code is not exposed by xamarin , so `try catch` is not helpful .

Try to call `DisplayPromptAsync` function on Main thread.

```
Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () =>
{
      rejectReason = await Application.Current.MainPage.DisplayPromptAsync("Reject Reason",
                "Are you sure you want to reject Order Number: " + selectedItem.OrderNumber
                + " and Company: " + selectedItem.Company, "OK", "Cancel");    
});
```