# System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: 'Index must be within the bounds of the List. when adding a new item to ObservableCollection

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, mvvm, entity-framework-core, maui

This happens on a Xamarin.Forms app.
It is a simple app about making lists.

I got two pages: one with the lists and another to show the list's items. The error happens on the latter when I try to add a new item to an `ObservableCollection`.

This is a simplified version of the ViewModel:

```
    public ObservableCollection<ListItem> Items { get; }
    public Command AddItemCommand { get; }

    public ItemsViewModel()
    {  
        Items = new ObservableCollection<ListItem>();

        AddItemCommand = new Command(OnAddItem);;
    }

    private async void OnAddItem()
    {
        await Device.InvokeOnMainThreadAsync(async () =>
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(NewItemText))
                return;

            ListItem listITem = new ListItem()
            {
                ListId = _currentList.ListId,
                Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
                Text = NewItemText
            };

            Items.Add(listITem);

            _currentList.ListItems.Add(listITem);
            await DataStore.UpdateItemAsync(_currentList);

            NewItemText = string.Empty;
        });
    }
```

The error happens on the `Items.Add(listITem);` call.

Tried wrapping the call on `Device.InvokeOnMainThreadAsync` with no luck.

The curious thing is it just happens on the second time I access the page.

The full project can be found on my GitHub:
https://github.com/JeffersonAmori/ListApp

Comment: any exception should have a stack trace that will show you the origin of the exception.  You should start there.  Is `Items` bound to anything in your XAML?

Comment: **1)** `Items.Add..` line looks correct - it is executed on MainThread by the surrounding block. Therefore, there is some interaction between this code and code elsewhere (if not your code, then its an XF bug). **2)** What are the types of `ListItem` and  `_currentList.ListItems`? (Making sure these aren't UI types.) **3)** Add to question any other xaml or code that refers to `Items`. **4)** Did you make that github repo **public**? I think not - it gives 404 when I try to access. **5)** Testing on  iOS or where? **6)** Why did you tag with `maui`? with `entity-framework-core`?

Comment: ... **7)** Shouldn't matter, but does it still error if comment out the two lines after the bad one: `_currentList.ListItems.Add(...); await DataStore...;` (Just a sanity check to be sure the error really is what it seems to be.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It wouldn't surprise me if the error stopped happening if you lessen the chance for XForms to intervene before you've done the `Add`. (I'm hypothesizing that the underlying problem is a latent XForms bug.):

```cs
    private async void OnAddItem()
    {
        // --- ASSUME we are already on MainThread. ---
        // --- Avoid "await" (and any "..Invoke..Async") until after "Items.Add". ---
        
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(NewItemText))
            return;

        ListItem listITem = new ListItem()
        {
            ListId = _currentList.ListId,
            Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
            Text = NewItemText
        };
        
        Items.Add(listITem);
        
        _currentList.ListItems.Add(listITem);
        NewItemText = string.Empty;

        // ----- await Potentially slow operation(s) AFTER all quick UI calls. -----
        
        await DataStore.UpdateItemAsync(_currentList);
    }
```

CAVEAT #1: This doesn't fix any underlying problem, it just might make it happen less often. If its an XF problem, you might have to wrap your code in `try..catch`. In `catch`, determine if the item got added. If not try adding it again. Messy.

CAVEAT #2: This assumes `OnAddItem` is only called from MainThread. That will be true, if you never call it directly yourself - UI code will invoke the command on main thread.

CAVEAT #3: Assumes that all of the types involved (especially ListItem and _currentList.ListItems) are not UI types - they have no dependencies on Xamarin.Forms View classes.

Comment: I'm accepting this answer as it pointed me in the right direction.

I was unable to pinpoint the root cause of my bug, but changing the way I was navigating between the pages solved the issue.

Look's like it was some thread related problem.

For reference now it is possible to check the GitHub link on the original question as it is now public.

Thanks for the help, much appreciated.

Comment: Glad that helped. I’d like to see an answer that shows the change you made.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem was the way the app was navigating between pages.
Before - when the error occurred - it was navigating using flyout routes via the flyout menu. Now I'm explicit registering the routes on code behind and pushing them into the navigation stack programmatically when the user clicks one of the items on the `ColletcionView`. This way I'm not reusing pages anymore.

```
    public AppShell()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Routing.RegisterRoute(nameof(ItemsPage), typeof(ItemsPage));
    }
```

and then

```
    async private void OnListSelected(List list)
    {
        if (list == null)
            return;

        await Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"{nameof(ItemsPage)}?{nameof(ItemsViewModel.ListId)}={list.ListId}");
    }
```

This way I seems to get the threads to behavior correctly and always get a new list when navigating between pages as they are pushed/popped into/from the navigation stack.

Bear in mind there's some guess work on this answer as I'm just getting back into Xamari.Forms and I'm fairly new to Shell.

Thanks again [toolmakersteve](https://stackoverflow.com/users/199364/toolmakersteve) for the insights.

Cheers.